# wkwebview post Request Receive no return value

Tags: ios, objective-c, wkwebview

Why is there no return value in this place?

```
    NSString *jscript = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"post('%@',{%@});", self.URLString, self.postData];

[self.wkWebView evaluateJavaScript:jscript completionHandler:^(id object, NSError * _Nullable error) {
    NSLog(@"%@",object);// object is null

}];
```

But the return value is loaded on the page, just started to do iOS, please help

Comment: Print `error` as well.

Comment: error is also null

Comment: Likely the `post` call from JS is an async one, which means it likely completes after the `evaluateJavaScript` returns.